# Write one SQL query for multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, prepared-statement

I am creating a simple database for a forum. I have a category table `forum_categories` which looks like this:

```
`cat_id` INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cat_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`cat_desc` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`),
UNIQUE KEY (`cat_title`)
```

And a topics table `forum_topics` which looks like this:

```
`topic_id` INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cat_id` INT(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key with forum_categories table',
`user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key with users table',
`topic_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`topic_desc` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`topic_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES forum_categories (`cat_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='forum topics';
```

Now when I select a categroy I just want the topics to show, where the cat_id fields are equal to each other.

Example:
 
Category 1 has cat_id = 1
 
Category 2 has cat_id = 2

Topic 1 has cat_id = 1
Topic 2 has cat_id = 2

Now when category 1 is selected I just want topic 1 to show. If category2 is selected I just want topic 2 to show.
 
This query achieves that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_categories fc 
JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id 
WHERE fc.cat_id = 1 
ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC
```

Now, I would like to not have one query for every category, if that is possible. Trying to do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_categories fc 
JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id 
WHERE fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id 
ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC
```

or this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_categories fc 
JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id 
ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC
```

Shows topic 1 and 2 in both categories. Is there a way to have one query for all categories?

Comment: instead of using "using" use on proper alias like fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id

Comment: something like SELECT * FROM forum_categories fc JOIN forum_topics ft on fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC

Comment: Thank you! It does not work but then I guess I made a mistake somewhere else! Thank you for your help!

Comment: *Is there a way to have one query for all categories?* try a stored procedure or paramterized queries that accepts a category ID as input

Comment: I think parameterized queries are what you are looking for OP. It's a great way to write a query that can be reusable if all you want to change is an input value. My answer covers this as well as a MySQL reference to prepared statements. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a query that pulls this data for all categories, you can join the two tables together, on the condition that the cat_id is equal. This would look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_categories fc
JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id
ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC;
```

If you want to query for a specific category, you can put that in your WHERE statement, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_categories fc
JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id
WHERE fc.cat_id = 1 // Or whatever you want.
ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC;
```

I think one issue you might be having is that you want this to be reusable, where you can write one query and change the cat_id as needed. If that is the case, I recommend you look into prepared statements.

What a prepared statement does is create a query with a parameter value that you insert as needed. Here is an example:

```
PREPARE stmnt FROM 
    'SELECT * 
    FROM forum_categories fc
    JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id
    WHERE fc.cat_id = ?
    ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC';

SET @a = 1;

EXECUTE stmnt USING @a;
```

When you do this, you can assign a new variable (@b, @c) with whatever you want. All you'd have to do is call `EXECUTE stmnt` each time, without having to always rewrite that query.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9161/5) that covers all three of my examples for you.

Here is a reference to MySQL [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: Wow! What an amazing answer!! Thank you so much!!! I can not upgrade this but i will as soon as i have enough reputation.

Comment: No need to stress over it - I'm here to help and that's what I did. This was a good question, I gave it a +1. Keep asking these tricky thought-provoking questions and you'll build up your own reputation in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM forum_categories fc
  JOIN forum_topics ft
    ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id
 WHERE fc.cat_id = 1 -- or whatever category you want
 ORDER
    BY ft.topic_date DESC
```

Comment: There is no error message it just shows all the topics no matter which categroy I choose. I guess I made a mistake else where then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, if you want just a special category, you need an additional WHERE clause (see my updated answer)

Comment: Wow!! That works! Is it possible that I do something like WHERE fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id? Because I would like to have one query for all the categories. Not a seperate query for each category, if that is possible?

Comment: You already did it. `WHERE fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id` is just another way of joining two tables.

Comment: Hmmm...that is the query without the WHERE clause. It returns all topics with there corresponding categories.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! When I do this: `SELECT * FROM forum_categories fc JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id WHERE fc.cat_id = 1 ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC` It just shows the cat_id 1 topics, as intented. But if I do this: `SELECT * FROM forum_categories fc JOIN forum_topics ft ON fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id WHERE fc.cat_id = ft.cat_id ORDER BY ft.topic_date DESC`it does not work.

Comment: I really don't know what you expect. What "does not work" mean? Can you provide an example result in your question?

Comment: I updated the question. I hope that clarifies it. I am sorry, I am really new to all this!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   cat_title,
   cat_desc,
   topic_title,
   topic_desc
FROM forum_categories
INNER JOIN forum_topics
   USING(cat_id)
WHERE cat_id = x;
```